# How to make Enemy Sprite Flip?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, velocity, rigid-bodies

I got an Enemy and I wanna flip the Sprite when his X - Value is increasing and the Opposite, in my PlayerMovement Skript this kind of Method worked but now it doesn't anymore.

```
 private void UpdateDirection()

 {
     if (transform.position.x < -.1f) 
     {
         spr.flipX = true; 
     }
     else
     {
         spr.flipX = false; 
     }
 }
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Thank you for your question. However it seems like you are not familiar with the guide of Stack Overflow to [How To: Ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Please read it and adjust your question accordingly by using the [Edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/77068047/edit) option. Happy coding!

Comment: also i have no idea how that worked before because your checking if the players x position is less than 0?

Answer (score 0):

Does it need to check if its moved, cant you just check the rigidbodys velocity like this:

```
private Rigidbody2D m_Rigidbody;

void Awake() {
    m_Rigidbody = GetComponent<Rigidbody>();
}
void Update() {
    DirectionCheck();
}

private void DirectionCheck() {
    if (m_Rigidbody.velocity.x > 0 && transform.localScale.x < 0)
        Flip();
    else if (m_Rigidbody.velocity.x < 0 && transform.localScale.x > 0)
        Flip();
}
private void Flip() {
    Vector2 newScale = transform.localScale;
    newScale.x *= -1;
    transform.localScale = newScale;
}
```